# Adding A Logo in Header Under Primary Menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, header, graphical-logo

thanks for taking the time to read this. My title pretty much sums up what I am having problems with. Typically I fumble my way through these types of things but it ends up getting done the wrong way and as a result my websites end up having problems. I am trying to learn the correct way to code everything and have it be nice and clean.

This is a WordPress template I am using. Here is a link to my [site](http://bceverything.com).I have setup a child theme and like the way most of it is looking so far except I would like to put a site-logo on all of my pages under the "menu-primary" as it is called in the Header. In the top left hand corner of the page is where my site title and my site slogan or whatever you call it are located. Below that is my menu (menu-primary) and all of that mentioned falls into the header. My template does not allow me to insert a logo in the Header in settings or customizations. I would like to insert a site-logo about half-way down the page right underneath the menu section. I suppose I should probably make it clickable to my homepage or something and make sure it is a valid [XHTML clickable header image](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2007/10/22/valid-xhtml-clickable-header-images)? I am not sure if that is a bad idea or not seeing as the site title will link back to the homepage. Is it bad to have two links to the same place on all of my pages? I am assuming so. I don't really need the image to link I guess.

Is there anyone that can help me with this? I appreciate all input. This site has been extremely helpful in teaching me fundamentals. I see ways to do what I want here but I am afraid they are all not proper ways to do it. Thanks again!

Here is the header.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Header Template
 *
 * The header template is generally used on every page of your site. Nearly all other templates call it 
 * somewhere near the top of the file. It is used mostly as an opening wrapper, which is closed with the 
 * footer.php file. It also executes key functions needed by the theme, child themes, and plugins. 
 *
 * @package Save for Web
 * @subpackage Template
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo( 'html_type' ); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php hybrid_document_title(); ?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

<?php wp_head(); // wp_head ?>

</head>

<body class="<?php hybrid_body_class(); ?>">

    <?php do_atomic( 'open_body' ); // saveforweb_open_body ?>

    <div id="container">

        <?php do_atomic( 'before_header' ); // saveforweb_before_header ?>

        <div id="header">

            <div class="fixed">

                <?php do_atomic( 'open_header' ); // saveforweb_open_header ?>

                <div class="wrap">

                    <div id="branding">
                        <?php hybrid_site_title(); ?>
                        <?php hybrid_site_description(); ?>
                    </div><!-- #branding -->

                    <?php get_template_part( 'menu', 'primary' ); // Loads the menu-primary.php template. ?>

                    <?php get_sidebar( 'header' ); // Loads the sidebar-header.php template. ?>

                    <?php do_atomic( 'header' ); // saveforweb_header ?>

                </div><!-- .wrap -->

                <?php do_atomic( 'close_header' ); // saveforweb_close_header ?>

            </div><!-- .fixed -->

        </div><!-- #header -->

        <?php do_atomic( 'after_header' ); // saveforweb_after_header ?>

        <?php do_atomic( 'before_main' ); // saveforweb_before_main ?>

        <div id="main">

            <div class="wrap">

            <?php do_atomic( 'open_main' ); // saveforweb_open_main ?>
```

Here is the menu-primary.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Primary Menu Template
 *
 * Displays the Primary Menu if it has active menu items.
 *
 * @package Save for Web
 * @subpackage Template
 */

if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>

    <?php do_atomic( 'before_menu_primary' ); // saveforweb_before_menu_primary ?>

    <div id="menu-primary" class="menu-container">

            <?php do_atomic( 'open_menu_primary' ); // saveforweb_open_menu_primary ?>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'container_class' => 'menu', 'menu_class' => '', 'menu_id' => 'menu-primary-items', 'fallback_cb' => '' ) ); ?>

            <?php do_atomic( 'close_menu_primary' ); // saveforweb_close_menu_primary ?>

    </div><!-- #menu-primary .menu-container -->

    <?php do_atomic( 'after_menu_primary' ); // saveforweb_after_menu_primary ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It's hard for us to answer your questions without knowing anything about how this theme is put together.  You'll likely need to edit whatever template file has the code for the menu, then add the logo to the end of it.  It shouldn't be hard at all but I don't think it's something that we can help you with unless we have a lot more information.

Comment: I tried to describe how to do what @ChrisHerbert recommends. I want to say I'm not sure what other information you could give us. I think your question could even be more concise. However, we can't tell you _exactly_ how to do it since we don't have the template in front of us; this is the nature of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone! Chris, what kind of additional info would be helpful?  I made an edit an included the header.php  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It looks like the menu is probably contained in menu-primary.php

Answer (score 1):

The function that generates the menu for you is most likely `wp_nav_menu`. So first step is finding out where it's located in the template source code. Maybe in header.php for example. Make sure it's parameter says "theme_location => 'menu-primary'" so that you have the right menu, in case your template has several.

Next, copy this code and paste it below:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/..." alt="" title="" /></a>
```

You will have to adjust the src=... part so that it matches the URL for your header image.

Comment: Hey Calle! Thanks for the reply.  I edited the above question and included both the header.php and the menu-primary.php.  The menu-primary.php is where the wp_nav_menu is. I added the code you suggested (not shown in my edit) and I didn't see any change.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Look at the source code of the website (right click in browser, view source), where the image is supposed to be. Is the img tag there? Is the <a href.. <img... stuff there? If not, you didn't edit the right file. Is it there but nothing is showing? Then the URL of the image is not right. Modify `src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/images/..."` accordingly.